# Is it possible to style the Azure Maps Popup Close Button or create your own instead?

Tags: azure-maps

I am using the Azure Maps service in a test to see if it will work for us in a project we are developing. The map service works fine for what we need, but the popup's standard close button is extremely small. Is there a way we can apply some CSS styling to the existing close button, or can we create our own instead of using the built in one?

This is what the close button looks like on our test service now:
[image: Screen Snip of Close Button]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!

It was rather simple. I took a guess and set the closeButton option to false, and on my button control I added a "onclick" attribute with the value of "popup.close()" and it worked just fine.